# How to use the .find() method in Sails.js v1 to search case-insensitive

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

Long story short, the find method search in a case-sensitive way, I want it to search in non case-sensitive. Make Contains Modifier Case Insensitive In Mongo.

```
return res.send(await Template.find({
  where: { 'title' : { startsWith : 'f' }
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I solved it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE 'some_table' convert TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Sails [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models) say "In order to fix this you can set the tables in your MySQL database to a case sensitive collation such as utf8_bin." I use "utf8_unicode_ci" becouse this is case-insensitive collation.